# Call to ioctl() results in errno indicating "Bad address"

Tags: c, sockets, ioctl

I'm getting the following error:

```
wlan_config_vap_priv_int vap lan0 cmd cpauth val 0(0) error: Bad address
```

Which is from the print in wlan_config_vap_priv_int. Does anyone know what might be causing the "Bad address" error?

From [why does ioctl return "bad address"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769770/why-does-ioctl-return-bad-address) I suspect the culprit may be the ioctl call, but I don't see why.

```
int wlan_config_vap_priv(char *vap, char *cmd, char * val) {
    int fd, ret;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    param_t fp;

    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, vap, IFNAMSIZ);
    strncpy(fp.cmd, cmd, sizeof(fp.cmd));
    strncpy(fp.val, val, sizeof(fp.val));
    ifr.ifr_data = (void *) &fp;
    printf("%s:%d: config vap %s priv %s=%s\n", __func__, __LINE__, vap, cmd, val);
    if((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }
    ret = ioctl(fd, SIOCSPARAM, &ifr);
    close(fd);
    return (ret);
}

int wlan_config_vap_priv_int(uint8_t rId, char *vap, char *cmd, int val) {

    char buf[32];
    int ret;

    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", val);
    ret = wlan_config_vap_priv(vap, cmd, buf);
    if (ret < 0) {
        CW_LOG_ERR("%s vap %s cmd %s val %s(%d) error: %s\n",
                    __FUNCTION__, vap, cmd, buf, val, strerror(errno));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: What is `SIOCSPARAM` ? Does the call fail on `ioctl` or on `socket`? The line it's 
 just CW_LOG_ERR function printin it. EFAULT is a strange errno to get, did you clear errno before calling `wlan_config_vap_priv`?

Comment: Using `strncpy(str, str2, sizeof(str))` is bad practice, in case `strlen(str2) == sizeof(str)` string will be not null terminated. Use `strscpy`.

Comment: I can't find any mention of `SIOCSPARAM`, either on Google, in man pages, in the Linux kernel source, or in C headers ...

Comment: I implemented SIOCSPARAM myself, so it's not a standard ioctl. @o11c

Comment: @KamilCuk you are saying I should use sizeof(str2) instead?

Comment: I say you shouldn't expect a null terminated string after using `strncpy` function, no matter what you use with it. If you expect strings to be null terminated, use `strscpy`. Forget about `strncpy`.     Does the negative value returned by `wlan_config_vap_priv` is returned by ioctl call or by socket call? "How" did you implemented ioctl call? How is SIOCSPARAM defined? What kind of system/environment is this?

Comment: "I implemented SIOCSPARAM myself". Only you can tell why your ioctl returns an error then.

Comment: Please include your kernel part for `SIOCSPARAM`. Otherwise this question does not provide enough information.

Comment: @KamilCuk `strscpy` is for Kernel. This seems like user-space code.

Comment: `strscpy` is not a standard C library function.  It's probably better to just learn how to use `strncpy` the right way.

Comment: Two functions with no information on what you pass to them, what your environment and hardware are, what your custom parts are, etc. - do not a question make. There is no point in speculating from such incomplete data.

Answer (score 0):

Your information is incomplete because you do not have the Kernel part for `SIOCSPARAM`.

However according to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html, this error happens when *argp* references an inaccessible memory area

> EFAULT *argp* references an inaccessible memory area.

Your source strings do not have size attached to them. Using `strncpy` on this string is unsafe and could be the culprit. You can try using something like `snprintf`.